# JSON Deserialize Object HTTPWebResponse

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to take my Web Request JSON output and parse it.  Here is the output

```
{
    "kind":"internal",
    "name":"SplashPageToggle_dg",
    "fullPath":"SplashPageToggle_dg",
    "generation":1255326,
    "selfLink":"https://link",
    "type":"stri ng",
    "records":[
        {
            "name":"enable_app1",
            "data":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app2",
            "da ta":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app3",
            "data":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app4",
            "data":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app5",
            "data":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app6",
            "data":"1"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app7",
            "data":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app8",
            "data":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app9",
            "data":"0"
        },
        {
            "name":"enable_app10",
            "data":"0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created public classes for these results

```
public class RootObject
{
   public string kind { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string fullPath { get; set; }
   public int generation { get; set; }
   public string selfLink { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
   public List<Record> records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string data { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to deserialize the Record class and choose the name, I get the name from the RootObject class.  Here is my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string url = "URL";    
   HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   getRequest.Method = "GET";
   getRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UN", "PW");   
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
      RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
      (
         delegate { return true; }
      );

   var getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();    
   Stream newStream = getResponse.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);    
   var result = sr.ReadToEnd();    
   var splashInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(result);

   Console.WriteLine(splashInfo.name);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to deserialize your JSON into the wrong class.

Change this line:

```
var splashInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Record>(result);
```

to this:

```
var splashInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2xR7hO

Comment: And just for the OP, splashInfo will now contain a deserialized list of record objects, so you can call splashInfo.records to return them all.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks guys.

Comment: @Dispersia. How can the list be populated automatically ? Is it possible to say fx. List.add() or something ?  I don't get how the list is automatically populated from the Json

Comment: @Brian Rogers: Maybe you can answer that

Comment: @uba2012 I'm not going to be able to explain how deserialization works in the space of a comment. Suffice it to say that Json.Net uses [reflection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) on the target class(es) to discover the properties and populate them from the JSON. If you want to know more details, consider [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about the part(s) you don't understand, or download and step through the [Json.Net source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) to see for yourself how it works.

Comment: @Brian Rogers. Thanks for you answer, I will do some more research. It's just like magic it seems. Like if I named my class variables namme instead of name, and the JSON returned name, it is magical how it is possible to deserialise in that scenario. Anyways thanks for your time. I have some research to do know and I may post a question soon.