# Scrape Data from network request VB.net

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

i am using VB.net to scrape data and update an ExcelFile.
I am facing a problem.
Da data are visible just in a network response. And I don't know how to get it.
They are never visible in source code.

This is the network header:
[image]

This is the network payload:
[image]

And this is the response i need to get, the value is 1976500

[image]

I don't know how to get it. I am pretty new in web scraping, i can get datas from html but not from here.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your framework and explain what classes/methods are you using?  It can be hard to help without that.  What I can see in your last image looks like JSON, in which case you probably just need to do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38312627/json-deserialize-object-httpwebresponse)

Comment: Are you sure this is scraping and not requesting data via some webapi?  Very, very different techniques.  Maybe update your question with abit of info and examples about how you're getting to this point?